# Set facebook canvas app height equal to the height of the Facebook sidebar

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, facebook

I have a facebook canvas app setup with width and height as fluid in the Advanced app settings.

What I need to achieve is to set the height of my canvas app equal to the height of the Facebook sidebar(side pane where all the FB adds and links appear). 
Currently the canvas app is set to fluid which sets the height of the app equal to the view area, so what happens is the FB sidebar is bit taller than the view area and scrolls the page by default and hence creates space below my canvas app.

I have tried setting the height to fixed but then it removes the scroll bar(adds overflow hidden to the iframe) from the iframe which is not desirable as the app contains content which exceeds the fixed height.

Check this for better understanding http://jsfiddle.net/v2QKN/5/

Comment: Do you have a screenshot of the space its adding below your application so we have a better understanding of the problem?

Comment: I have added a jsfiddle in my question..check it out

Answer (score 1):

### Just stop the scroll when they have reached the bottom

Ok, this is not probably the neatest solution out there.
But that white space kept happening to me when the body inside the iframe was fully scrolled already, so the main window scrolling took over.

So, a very effective solution for me is simply stopping the scroll when I don't need it anymore. Users are going to scroll inside the canvas 99% of times. So to do this we only need a few lines of javascript:

```
$("body").on("mousewheel", function(e) {

  if ( ( window.innerHeight + document.body.scrollTop) >= $("body").height()  ) {
    e.preventDefault();
    e.stopPropagation();
    document.body.scrollTop = document.body.scrollTop - 1;
  }

});
```

See it in action here: https://apps.facebook.com/hiphopexpress/

Note: the mouse wheel event is only triggered by mouse wheels. Still, with this solution we are improving the experience of the vast majority of our desktop users.

Comment: This works "most of the time", I've also added `FB.Canvas.scrollTo(0,0);` to make sure I'm scrolling the parent window to the top.

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible to set your canvas app to be the height of the sidebar, however you can use a fixed canvas height along with the Javascript SDK [setAutoGrow](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.Canvas.setAutoGrow/) function which will resize the frame that the app is contained in to fit it's content. I think this is your best option, if you don't want the side bar to be taller than your app content.

Comment: but for setAutoGrow to work I'll have to set the height to be fixed and not fluid, this will remove the scrolls from my app and I won't be able to scroll through my app.

Comment: Yes, but the point of AutoGrow is that it always fits your apps height, therefore you shouldn't ever need scrollbars. It won't affect scrollbars within the app iFrame, just the main window scrollbar.

Comment: actually the content in my app is loaded whenever the user scrolls to the bottom(lazy loading)...its basically a grid. Will this be handled by the setAutoGrow handler?? Also I am bit hesitant because I don't want huge page scroll bar as then it will add white space to the sidebar section.

Comment: You have no choice really, you'll either get white space below your app or white space below the sidebar.

If you want to have ultimate control over the scrolling, you should have an iFrame *inside* your canvas app (basically a double iFrame) in which you do all the scroll-handling in your own code, but otherwise you'll have to live with setAutoGrow.

You can trigger that autogrow function at any time, perhaps in the success function handler of your lazy loading Javascript?

Comment: @Mathew: Thanks for the reply, well one way is that instead off adding another inframe in my app I can make div scroll-able by specifying a height and have the canvas app set to fixed height in the settings panel.

Comment: Right, but you aren't going to be able to discover the height of the right column (because it's located in a different domain, most Javascript in your App iFrame won't be able to access DOM elements from the parent Facebook frame)

Comment: No No...I meant I'll fix the height to 'Fixed(800px)' in the FB settings panel and add scrolls to my canvas body tag.